# Views filter with per-user black tag list

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I want to implement such a scheme: each material on the site has a field with one or more tags, and user profiles has fields "white tag list" and "black tag list" with zero of more tags. A material must be shown to user only if it has at least one tag from user's individual white list and has not tags from user's black list.

I want to create a view with these filters. But I cannot implement black list logic. I tried to do it with relations and contextual filters. I tried to make some PHP code in contextual filter. I googled examples for two weeks and now I am totally puzzled.